# Converting iterator to list changes the iterator

Tags: python, list, iterator

The following code produces some very strange results

```
import re
string = "test test test"
positions = re.finditer("test", string)
print (list(positions))
print (list(positions))
```

Output:

```
[<Match object...>, <Match object...>, <Match object...>]
[]
```

Now, I think I know what's going on here. The first `list` call "exhausts" the iterator (so it "uses the iterator up", like in a generator, in the process of creating a list from the iterator) so then when the second call to `list` is made, the iterator is gone and we get an empty list. This seems to be confirmed by the paragraph below, although I am am trying to understand some of the things they are saying here, so I am not entirely happy with this explanation (if it is the right one):

> A container object (such as a list) produces a fresh new iterator
>   each time you pass it to the iter() function or use it in a for loop.
>   Attempting this with an iterator will just return the same exhausted
>   iterator object used in the previous iteration pass, making it appear
>   like an empty container.

The above paragraph is from [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator).

I do not really understand what they are saying in the first sentence in the above paragraph, especially with regards to passing to the `iter()` function, and I do not know how they connect usage in a for loop to a list producing a fresh new iterator. The second sentence, though, seems closer to what I first thought was going on in the code above.

If anyone can help me clear up the confusion here, I would appreciate it immensely.

**NOTE:**

I am using Python 3.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
positions = re.finditer("test", string)
```

[It returns a one-shot iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer).  Then you called `list(positions)` *twice* on the same iterator.

So for the second call, it was already exhausted.

Lists will give you a fresh iterator every time you iterate them, so there is no exhausting behaviour on a list itself.  Compare the behaviour below to understand the piece of documentation you quoted:

```
>>> L = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> list(L)
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> list(L)
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> iter_L = iter(L)  # calls L.__iter__() and returns you a one-shot iterator
>>> list(iter_L)
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> list(iter_L)
[]
```

Comment: one-shot iterator?

Comment: Yes.  You can only iterate it once.

Comment: Ok, but that was pretty much what I said I thought already (that it exhausts the iterator the first time, then the second time it's gone). But nevermind, I think I have figured out what the paragraph I have quoted in my question is saying.

Comment: Haha, was just about to answer my own question with exactly the latest edit you have made on your answer (with the code starting with `L = ['a'...`). But I see you beat me to it

Comment: Note that the behaviour you see in the original question has nothing to do with `list.__iter__`, and everything to do with the contract of `re.finditer`.

Comment: Ok, so to be clear: Calling `list(iterator_object)` actually runs through the iterator (in the process of creating the list) because there is no other way of accessing elements in an iterator (so that we may create a list containing those elements), other than to actually exhaust the iterator?

Comment: Yes, I understand that `re.finditer` just returns an iterator

Comment: Yep, for any object, using `list(thing)` just does the equivalent of:  `result = []; for x in thing: result.append(x)`

Answer (score 0):

When list() runs over an iterator, it basically calls next() on it until it raises the exception StopIteration and then appends each thing that the next() returns to a list, then returns that list. Basically, an implementation of list(iter) could be:

```
my_list(iter):
    output = []
    try:
        while True:
            output.append(iter.next())
    except StopIteration:
        return output
```

By the way, a `for` loop does the exact same thing, but instead of `output.append(iter.next())` it does the body of the loop.